# How to select data from database with same query but different condition in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

1. student
2. attendance

I want to `select` the attendance of students by conditions of year and exam_type (midterm, final) and show in one table.

```
$student_attendance1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
FROM student_attendance 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.student_id = student_attendance.student_id 
WHERE attendance_year=$attendance_year 
AND exam_type=1");

$row_studend_attendance1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_attendance1);

$studend_attendance2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
FROM student_attendance 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.student_id = student_attendance.student_id 
WHERE attendance_year=$attendance_year 
AND exam_type=1");

$row_studend_attendance2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_attendance2);
```

How can I do this? [DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Owyd.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I've got some questions : What are you trying to do ? Retrieve the datas or display it ? What have you already tried to do this, and what is the problem you encountered ?

Comment: Thanks bro. I want to display the data in a table with spetial format . How two display the two exams attendance in one table???

Comment: I attached the table image, in above question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suppose you always have one, and only one, row per student for exam_type = 1 or exam_type = 2(?) (By the way, your two queries, as you wrote them, are absolutely identical...)

You should add a clause like "ORDER BY student.student_id ASC" to be sure you retrieve the datas from your two queries in the same order.

Then, all you have to do is display your datas into a table :

```
<?php
$student_attendance1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
FROM student_attendance 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.student_id = student_attendance.student_id 
WHERE attendance_year=$attendance_year 
AND exam_type=1 ORDER BY student.student_id ASC");

$studend_attendance2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
FROM student_attendance 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.student_id = student_attendance.student_id 
WHERE attendance_year=$attendance_year 
AND exam_type=2 ORDER BY student.student_id ASC");

while($row_studend_attendance1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_attendance1)) {
    $row_studend_attendance2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student_attendance2);
?> // Close your PHP tag.

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>F/Name</th>
        <th>Exams</th>
        <th>Year days</th>
        <th>Present</th>
        <th>Absent</th>
        <th>Sickness</th>
        <th>Permission</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"><?= $row_studend_attendance1['student_id']  ?></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><?= $row_studend_attendance1['surname']  ?></td>
        <td rowspan="3"><?= $row_studend_attendance1['firstname']  ?></td>
        <td>Midterm</td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['year_days']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['present']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['absent']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['sickness']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['permission']  ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Final</td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance2['year_days']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance2['present']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance2['absent']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance2['sickness']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance2['permission']  ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sum</td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['year_days'] + $row_studend_attendance2['year_days']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['present'] + $row_studend_attendance2['present']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['absent'] + $row_studend_attendance2['absent']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['sickness'] + $row_studend_attendance2['sickness']  ?></td>
        <td><?= $row_studend_attendance1['permission'] + $row_studend_attendance2['permission']  ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope I answer your question. If not, feel free to ask again.